# Incorrect displayed reputation difference after suspension/unsuspension

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, account-suspension

Bug: the displayed reputation difference on a user profile page is sometimes (always?) incorrect after an account suspension/unsuspension, e.g.:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I guess it shows this negative of a value (not quite twice your entire rep in the negatives) because you were suspended twice.

Comment: @Laurel If I am lucky to receive enough suspensions it'll become positive then, great 